# Monoidal categories that are not symmetric

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories

All the usual examples of monoidal categories that one comes across ($\mathbf{Set}$ with $\times$ as product, $R-\mathbf{Mod}$ with $\otimes$ etc.) are symmetric. Does anyone know an example, preferrably but not necessarily one that occurs in a theoretical mathematician's everyday life, of a monoidal category $C=(C,\otimes)$ that is not symmetric (i.e. $\exists A,B\in\operatorname{Obj}(C):A\otimes B\ncong B\otimes A$)?

Comment: how is set Abelian?

Comment: The term abelian category is reserved for additive categories with kernels and cokernels and for each map the image and coimage are isomorphic. The condition you are (not) looking for is called a braided monoidal category. So you are looking for monoidal categories that do not admit braidings.

Comment: An *abelian category* is a term drastically different from what you seem to have in mind.  The relevant terms are *symmetric monoidal category* and *braided monoidal category*, though both require more than just existence of isomorphism $A\otimes B\cong B\otimes A$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A example of a monoidal non symmetric category of $R$-bimodules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433078/a-example-of-a-monoidal-non-symmetric-category-of-r-bimodules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming, by "Abelian", you mean [symmetric monoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_monoidal_category), then a good example is the category of endofunctors $(\mathbf C, \circ, \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbf C})$ on a category $\mathbf C$. For instance, pick two distinct objects $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbf C$, and consider the "constantly $X$" and "constantly $Y$" functors. Clearly, the two composites of these functors are different. Categories of endofunctors are commonly encountered in category theory, since monoids therein are precisely [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)).

Answer (score 3):

Take any non-commutative monoid (for example the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on a set with at least two elements). Now consider it as a [discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_category) monoidal category. Then it has no symmetry.

Notice also that saying "being symmetric" is no good choice for monoidal categories, since symmetries provide additional *structure*, not just a property!